# Setting user name in rails locale based on admin and customer portals

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two portals admin and customer where in both the admin and the customer user can add comments on a particular section. When an admin creates a comment it shows created by admin and when the customer creates it shows created the the current user who is logged in. In the admin side I have a setting that when the admin creates it it enters the user name as admin.

I want to have this implementation: 1. For multiple users I want to customize the created by admin based on locale. i.e if it is created by admin it should pick the key from locale file and if it is created by customer it should show the current user who is logged in. How can i implement it? Any help would be appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can associate the author (admin or not) with each comment and display things differently later.

The view code could look like this:

```
<%= comment.author.admin? ? t(:admin) : comment.author.full_name %>
```

while having the following in your translation files (e.g. `en.yml`):

```
en:
  admin: Admin
```

I assume you use .erb files and your `User` model has the methods `admin?` and `full_name`. Adapt this example to your codebase. The `t` function come from the `I18n` module (see [this ruby guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)).